# why this simple sed script didn't work "nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -r 's/--/\\n/g'"

Tags: bash, shell, sed

the output of "nginx -V" is a mess.

> nginx version: nginx/1.9.3 (Ubuntu) built with OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul
>   2015 TLS SNI support enabled configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g
>   -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-

So, I write a simple script, redirect the err output to stdout and split the whole line:

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -r 's/--/\\n/g'
```

it didn't work.

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -r s/--/\\n/g
```

this works, I just don't know why.

Comment: @don_crissti ok~

Comment: `\\n` between single quotes is taken literally, that is `\\ ` and `n` so all occurrences of `--` are replaced with a backslash and a `n`. Without quotes the `\\n` resolves to `\n` (i.e. newline symbol).

Comment: @don_crissti thank you~, you are right~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to test:

```
$ echo "configure arguments: --with-cc-opt=" | | sed -r 's/--/\\n/g'
```

Doesn't work. But this:

```
$ echo "configure arguments: --with-cc-opt=" | sed -r 's/--/\n/g'
```

Does work. As this, also:

```
$ echo "configure arguments: --with-cc-opt=" | sed -r s/--/\\n/g
```

In short: The `'\\n'` does not work, it is interpreted as a backslash `\` and a `n`. Removing either one of the quoting mechanisms corrects the issue.